# Assert_receive to test Genserver message handlers?

Tags: erlang, elixir, integration-testing, gen-server

I would like to be able to catch messages going to my GenServer's `handle_info` in tests, to check those are what I intend to.

1/ Is there a way to print somehow every message coming through? 
2/ Using `assert_receive` is there a way to catch those messages? Should I set the `assert_receive` before or after the call to the external service that will result in the `handle_info` trigger? What syntax should I use?

I tried many combinations of `assert_receive` and I tried a `receive do...` to try and display messages getting in, with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Both [`ExUnit.Assertions.assert_receive/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html?#assert_receive/3) and [`ExUnit.Assertions.assert_received/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html?#assert_received/2) do assert messages coming into *the current process’ mailbox*. The former is to be called *either before or after* the message was actually sent:

> Asserts that a message matching `pattern` was or is going to be received within the `timeout` period, specified in milliseconds.

the latter is to be called *after*:

> Asserts that a message matching pattern was received and is in the current process’ mailbox.

That said, both are unlikely a good fit to test the existing `GenServer`. Messages are to arrive at the `GenServer`’s messagebox, this functionality is provided by OTP and you should not test it. If you need to log messages, add a call to [`Logger.log/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#log/3) to the [`handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?#c:handle_info/2) and check the log actually happens with [`ExUnit.CaptureLog.capture_log/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureLog.html?#capture_log/2). If it performs some action upon message arrival, test this action.

In general, you should test your code, not OTP.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for answering! Very helpful distinction between `assert_receive` and `assert_received`... 
About the test itself, I'm not testing OTP's behavior, just wanting to make sure that the other server emits what I expect to get as a message.

Comment: While one might intercept and debug mailbox processing with [`:erlang.sys`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html) module, I am not even sure the order of message processing is guaranteed.